# Create multiple project template Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution.
In that solution I have 3 projects (One C++ project and two C# projects)

I want to create a template for these 3 projects.  THis link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xkh1wxd8.aspx tells me:

1. On the File menu, click Export Template. The Export Template wizard opens.
2. Click Project Template.
3. **If you have more than one project in your current solution, select the projects you want to export to a template.**

But the wizard doesnt let me select several projects, **I can select only one from the drop down.**

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way for regular Template export to add multiple projects. The website you linked mentions the Export Template Wizard Extension, which allows you to do so, though. Unfortunately it is only available for Visual Studio 2010...VS Templating is really giving me the willies lately...

Comment: If you want to install multiple templates at the same time, you can compile them into a VSIX file (Visual Studio extension) - instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to create a template from multiple projects, because:

1. The procedure allows the creation of a project template from only
   one project for a solution.
2. It would be impossible (I think) for Visual Studio, to "understand" how to
   create a template from multiple projects.

Furthermore, about your C++ project, the process is slightly different, as stated in the documentation :

> You create Visual C++ templates differently from other language
>   templates. For more information, see [Designing a Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/96xz4cw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Inside
>   Visual C++ Wizards](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229844).